# Function Pointer Definition in Block Scope

Tags: c++, pointers, scope, function-pointers

I have a code section like this.

```
if (opt_choice == 1){
  double (*foo)(int , const MatrixXd& ); 
  double (*optimize)(double (*)(int, const MatrixXd&)) = function1;}
else if (opt_choice == 2){
  double (*foo)(int , const VectorXd& ); 
  double (*optimize)(double (*)(int, const VectorXd&)) = function2;}
```

I intend to use the same function pointer (here **optimize**) to point to different functions depending on user input. Similarly, I also have another function pointer **foo**, which takes a different argument depending on the user choice. foo is assigned to a different function later on.

```
switch (....)
case 1: foo = someFunction; break;  // error : foo is not declared in this scope
case 2: foo = someFunction2; break; 
...
```

Finally I wish to call both of these using their respective function pointers.

```
optimize(var1,foo); // error : optimize is not declared in this scope
```

As you may have guessed already, the compiler throws an error here as **foo** and **optimize** are not in scope since they were declared inside the if-statement.

Is there any way to achieve this? That is, keep **foo** and **optimize**  in scope until the end of the program. 
Thanks.

Comment: When I want to do something like that, I assign it to a variable.

Comment: You'll need to define the function pointers outside the `if` and `else` and set them inside the `if` or `else`.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Just do as you will with any variable?

Comment: Types must be known at compile-time, you can't do anything like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start by defining a type for the function pointers. Something like this:

```
typedef double (*FooFunc)(int, const MatrixXd&);
typedef double (*OptimizeFunc)(int, const VectorXd&);
```

Next, you can define the variables outside the scope of the `if`:

```
FooFunc foo;
OptFunc optimize;
```

Then assign inside the `if`:

```
if (opt_choice == 1)
{
    optimize = function1;
}
else if (opt_choice == 2)
{
    optimize = function2;
}
```

You never assign to `foo` in your first code snippet, so I don't know what to assign to it there, but it should be assigned to a function pointer that has the same signature as the `FooFunc` type. For the switch you'd do something like:

```
switch (...)
{
    case 1: foo = <some function with a FooFunc signature>; break
    case 2: foo = <some other function with a FooFunc signature>; break;
    // ...etc.
}
```